# Error on assigning a value to the label from the code behind

Tags: asp.net

My aspx markup:

```
<b><label id="patname" style="color:black"></label></b>
```

aspx.cs code behind:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstName) & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSurname))
{
    //patname.text=txtFirstName.toString() + '' + txtSurname.ToString();
    //patname.text = "test name";
    patname.InnerText = "Katherine Atkins";
}
```

I am trying to assign the value of the label from the code behind. But i am getting that the mentioned error.

I am getting error that patname is not exists in the current contest. Is there anything I am missing on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add attribute `runat="server"` to your label to access from code behind

```
<b><label id="patname" runat="server" style="color:black"></label></b>
```

or use asp label

```
<asp:Label id="patname" runat="server" style="color:black"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: OMG ! how i missed it .. Thanks for it @Ahmed Yousif.

Comment: Quickly i have a one more question here , i am getting the Empty character literal error when trying to assign like this patname.InnerText=txtFirstName.ToString() + '' + txtSurname.ToString();

Comment: what is the type of txtFirstName and txtSurname ?

Comment: String it is .. string txtFirstName = GetElementValue(xERoot, "txtFirstName");
                string txtSurname = GetElementValue(xERoot, "txtSurname");

Comment: My guess there is an issue with the concatenation

Comment: it has to be patname.InnerText=txtFirstName.ToString() + " " + txtSurname.ToString();